# Using python request library to dynamically get HTTP Error String

Tags: python, httprequest, urllib2

I've been asked to swap over from urllib2 to the requests library because the library is simpler to use and doesn't cause exceptions.

I can get the HTTP error code with response.status_code but I don't see a way to get the error message for that code. Normally, I wouldn't care, but I'm testing an API and the string is just as important.

Does anybody know of a simple way to get that string? I'm expecting 2 pieces something like:

'400':'Bad Request'

This is NOT a DUPLICATE

Some of the codes being returned have unique strings being sent by the application that I am testing. These strings cannot be looked up using this method: requests.status_codes._codes[error][0] Since the string is dynamically coming from the back end server. I was able to get this information using urllib using this method:

`import urllib2
 ...
 opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPSHandler(context=ctx))
 except urllib2.HTTPError as err:
   try: error_message = err.read()
 ...`

The question now is... is there a method of getting the dynamic http error string?  Thanks so much for being patient. The previous issue was closed so quickly I never got a chance to look at the answer, test it and re-ask by cleaning up the description.

Answer (score 2):

```
response = requests.get(url)
error_message = response.reason
```

Comment: @ Francisco Couzo... TY so much... The previous answer definitely did not work. For some reason I didn't see this in the public docs.

Answer (score 1):

In [HTTPResponse there's a `reason` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/http.client.html#httpresponse-objects) that returns the reason phrase from the response's status line. In [the requests library the `requests.Response class`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response) has an equivalent `reason` attribute that returns the same thing. Both should return the information from the response, not a fixed string based on the code.

Comment: @ Francisco Couzo...  TY so much... The previous answer definitely did not work.  For some reason I didn't see this in the public docs.